# window scroll event – need prevent bubbling or not?

Tags: javascript, events, callback, window

Which of these examples is more correct?

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', someFunc, false);
```

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', someFunc);
```

I know what is bubbling, it moves up from `element` to `window`. But what about any events on `window` – should we use callback `false` for this or not?
It looks like nonsense in this case, because the event has nowhere to go up, but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter `useCapture` specifies whether the event should be executed in the capturing or in the bubbling phase.

If it should be executed later than element event handlers, you have to use `false`(default).

If it should be executed earlier than element event handlers, you have to use `true`.

If no child elements have event listener, you can ignore the `useCapture` parameter.